# The meaning of the MIDDLE ENGLISH "nother"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, old-english, middle-english, old-norse

**Very specific expertise** is required here.

> The schoolmaster "shall not teche his scolers song **nor** other petite
>   lernyng, as the crosse rewe, redyng of the mateyns or for the psalter
>   or such other small thyngs, **nother redying of Englisshe**, but such as
>   shall concern lernynge of grammar" (link below)

What does "nother" mean here? I wanna say, based on its location, that it means "nor" as in "nor [shall they teach] the reading of English"; but, the seeming of the word makes it sound more like "neither". Another possibility: Could it be that the "neither (nother) nor" phrase is reversed? As in (again the following is a theory):

> The schoolmaster "shall not teche his scolers **nother redying of Englisshe** [nor] song **nor** other petite lernyng, as the crosse rewe, redyng of the mateyns or for the psalter or such other small thyngs, but such as
>   shall concern lernynge of grammar"

Link to the [quotation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U9L_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=schoolmaster%20%22shall%20not%20teche%20his%20scolers%20song&source=bl&ots=vMfbsx8Zkf&sig=jKPj5wTIxa5qNfJ4HgnO7GNUIWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAmoVChMIpo_g-6OpyAIVAp9yCh3UhgAI#v=onepage&q=schoolmaster%20%22shall%20not%20teche%20his%20scolers%20song&f=false) from *The Growth of English Schooling, 1340-1548* By Jo Ann Hoeppner Moran

Comment: I am not sure if this is sarcasm. But if it is, Middle English was spelled differently.

Comment: My guess is that this is an intermediate spelling of 'nauther' from which both 'neither' and  'nor' were derived.

Comment: So you agree that it could be "nor [shall they teach] the reading of English"?

Comment: Yes, I think it means 'nor' in this case.

Comment: I'm no scoler but if I'm reading this right, they had no singing, nor reading of English. How sad.

Comment: What is sadder, sir, is that during that time, even ENGLISH kings thought the English vernacular beneath them; they spoke French, wrote in Latin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context, the *OED* finds *nother* meaning "neither," "nor" (as in neither ... nor constructs), or "another" (i.e. "an other).  Here, the word is a continuation of the first *nor*, listing more things outside the curriculum for teaching those who take up careers in the church.

> The schoolmaster "shall not teche his scolers song nor other petite
>   lernyng,

The schoolmaster shall not teach his scholars song or other inconsequential subjects

> as the crosse rewe, redyng of the mateyns or for the psalter or such
>   other small thyngs,

such as the cross-row (a book of saying arranged alphabetically by the first letter of the first words of the sayings), prayers, books of psalms or other such inconsequential things.

> **nother** redying of Englisshe, but such as shall concern lernynge
>   of grammar"

*nor* [and not] reading English, but [he shall teach] those subjects that concern learning [Latin] grammar.